# Is Powershell command available for retrieving Azure Document Database account key?

Tags: powershell, azure, document-database

I am creating DocumentDB Account using ARM Template. Now want to get the Account Key once DocumentDB Account is created.

I know we can get these details from https://portal.azure.com but I want a command which will give context ( ex. with Get-AzureStorageAccountKey command we get key for storage account)

Comment: Did you ever find out how to do this?

Comment: Yes, I have created solution.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time.

Answer (score -1):

```
$ScriptPath = split-path -parent $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Definition 

$ResourceGroupName = "ResGrp"
$Location = "South Central US"
$DocDBAccountName = "testdocdbaccount"   
$TemplateFilePath = "DocumentDBJson\DocumentDB.json"   
$ParameterFilePath = "DocumentDBJson\DocumentDB.param.dev.json"

$PSOutputFolder= "$ScriptPath\PowerShellOutput"

$NewParameterFilePath = $ParameterFilePath.Replace(".json",".Deploy.json")    

(Get-Content "$ParameterFilePath") | Foreach-object {
    $_ -replace '\$Location\$', $Location `
        -replace '\$DocDBAccountName\$', $DocDBAccountName        
} |Set-Content "$NewParameterFilePath" -Force 

New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment -Name $DocDBAccountName -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName -Mode Complete -Force -TemplateFile "$ScriptPath\$TemplateFilePath" -location $Location -TemplateParameterFile "$NewParameterFilePath" | ConvertTo-Json | Out-File  "$PSOutputFolder\DocumentDB_$DocDBAccountName.json"

$DocDBFile = "$PSOutputFolder\DocumentDB_$DocumentDbAccount.json"
$docdbjson = Get-Content $DocDBFile | Out-String | ConvertFrom-Json
foreach ($v in $docdbjson.Outputs.keys.Value.Replace('" "','"|"').Split("|"))
{
    if($v -match "primaryMasterKey")
    {
       $DocumentDbKey= ($v.Split(":")[-1]).Replace('"','')
    }    
}
```

--------------------- DocumentDB.Json File -----------------------

```
    {
"$schema": "http://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2014-04-01-preview/deploymentTemplate.json#",
"contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
"parameters": {
    "databaseAccountName": {
        "type": "string"
    },
    "location": {
        "type": "string"
    }
},
"resources": [
    {
        "apiVersion": "2015-04-08",
        "type": "Microsoft.DocumentDb/databaseAccounts",
        "name": "[parameters('databaseAccountName')]",
        "location": "[parameters('location')]",
        "properties": {
            "name": "[parameters('databaseAccountName')]",
            "databaseAccountOfferType": "Standard"
        }
    }
],
"outputs": {
    "Keys": {
        "type": "object",
        "value": "[listKeys(resourceId('Microsoft.DocumentDb/databaseAccounts', parameters('databaseAccountName')), '2015-04-08')]"
    }       
}
}
```

------------------ DocumentDB.param.dev.json File -----------------

```
{
"$schema": "http://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2014-04-01-preview/deploymentParameters.json#",
"contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
"parameters": {
    "databaseAccountName": {
        "value": "$DocDBAccountName$"
    },
    "location": {
        "value": "$Location$"
    }   
}
}
```

Comment: A lot of code and no explanations. For others (and me) to understand this, could you please explain what is going on. Maybe reduce the code to a minimum?